# How to bind NSTabView selectedIndex inside an NSTabViewController?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode7, cocoa-bindings

Starting with OS X 10.10, there is a Storyboard friendly NSTabViewController.

Here is the description:

> NSTabViewController is a container view controller that displays a
>   single child view controller at a time from its childViewControllers.
>   It provides standard tab-style UI for user selection of tabs, or
>   allows custom UI to be easily created by providing targets for
>   bindings. ChildViewControllers’ views are lazily loaded; they are only
>   loaded once their tab is selected and visible. The NSTabViewController
>   is set as the delegate of its managed NSTabView

How do I set the bindings usually found in its contained NSTabView, such as selectedIndex ? I know they must be somewhere, but I can't find them. Th bindings section in empty in XCode when selecting NSTabViewController.